# longtable inserting pagebreak after \\ but not \tabularnewline or vice versa?

Tags: tables, longtable

I rememeber I read somewhere here that whether or not `\longtable` will break the page at the end of a certain line depends on how you end that line. In my memory it won't break at `\\` and not at `\tabularnewline` or vice versa, but I tried it and both seem false.

Is there some special 'end of line' symbol that we can use that prevents `\longtable` to (also) break the page at that point?

Comment: `\\ ` and `\pagebreak` allow page break. `\\*`and `\nopagebreak` prevent pagebreak. `\tabularnewline` is synonym to `\\ `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\\`  and `\tabularnewline` are the same thing. As elsewhere in LaTeX the `*` form prevents page breaks so `\\*` or `\tabularnewline*`